# Steam does not run

Tags: steam, games

new to linux systems here and thought of giving elementary os a try.

Everything going good so far, but i've encountered a problem with Steam.
I cannot seem to run it.

Downloaded the deb package from the official webite and ran it with gdebi, which sucessfully installed, but whenever i try to run it, the steam icon shows up, on the dock for a brief second and then it vanishes.

When using the terminal to run it, I get the following error.

[Click Here](https://jpst.it/O_Ne)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem as well. It's an issue with a library file. It can be bypassed. These commands in the terminal fixed it for me.

`cd $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`

`mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak`

`cd $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

`mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak`

Comment: This has fixed my problem and it now properly launches! Thank you very much Michael!

Answer (score 0):

**Never** install Steam from the .deb file in their website.

I'm going to explain you how you have to install Steam, but first you need to remove the current Steam you have installed.

To remove it, go to the .deb package you have downloaded and open it again with gdebi. Then click on remove.

To install steam you have various ways:

1º Go to the AppCentre, type Steam, and install it.

2º Open a terminal and type `sudo apt install steam`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance. But now it has given me a new install error. https://jpst.it/O__I

Comment: If you don't accept the steam license it obviously won't install.

Comment: I re-did it and it finally did show me the screen to accept its agreement, which it wasn't showing on the first try. it did install alright, but it still does not start. This is the error I now get, https://jpst.it/P1lZ

Comment: Did you install any PPA to update your graphics drivers or did you install any graphic driver from any .deb or tar.gz or similar file?
Also, what is your graphics card?
Steam works fine for me, so the problem must have been something you'd installed or a missing driver (if you have a really new computer)